# Generic function to get index of enum case from allCases

Tags: swift, indexing, enums

I have a class with a property that is a case from an Enum. I want to write a generic function to get the index of the case in the Enum's `allCases`.

I begin by defining a protocol `HasEnumCase` which simply states that adopters have an associated `CaseIterable & Equatable` type.

```
protocol HasEnumCase {
    associatedtype TheEnum: CaseIterable & Equatable
    var theCase: TheEnum { get }
}
```

This does not compile.

```
func getIndexInAllCases<T: HasEnumCase>(theInstance: T) -> Int {
    let allCases = T.TheEnum.allCases
    let index = allCases.firstIndex(of: theInstance.theCase)
    return index
}

//Cannot convert return expression of type 'T.TheEnum.AllCases.Index' to return type 'Int'
```

It compiles when I am using a concrete type.

```
enum MyEnum: CaseIterable {
    case zero
    case one
}

class HasEnumClass {
    typealias E = MyEnum
    var myEnum: MyEnum = .one
}

let h = HasEnumClass()
let caseIndex = type(of: h.myEnum).allCases.firstIndex(of: h.myEnum)
// caseIndex = 1
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The type `Index` defined on `Collection` doesn't have to be an `Int`, which is why you're seeing the error. You can use generic constraints to require this, though:

```
func getIndexInAllCases<T: HasEnumCase>(theInstance: T) -> Int where T.TheEnum.AllCases.Index == Int {
    // ...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

daltonclaybrook's reasoning and answer is correct: the issue is the type of `Index`.

I found I can also create an array from the result of `allCases` and the compiler will do the rest.

```
func getIndexInAllCases<T: HasEnumCase>(theInstance: T) -> Int {
    let allCases = Array(type(of: theInstance).TheEnum.allCases)
    let index = allCases.firstIndex(of: theInstance.theCase)!
    return index
}
```

Comment: `func getIndexInAllCases<T: HasEnumCase>(theInstance: T) -> T.TheEnum.AllCases.Index {
    return T.TheEnum.allCases.firstIndex(of: theInstance.theCase)!
}
`